# Visual studio build c++ project with Makefile using mingw

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I have a project written in C/C++ (libbpg-0.9.7 downloaded from [bellard.org](https://bellard.org/bpg/)). I want to build this library.

I created a Visual Studio project Visual C++ -> Makefile project (never done before). So there was many options and I don't know what to do. I read the README 
from libbpg :

> - Only cross-compilation from Linux is supported.
> - The following packages need to be installed: mingw64-gcc mingw64-libpng mingw64-libjpeg-turbo mingw64-SDL mingw64-SDL_image yasm

I installed mingw64-gcc by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwjiocILkbE) but I did not find how to install other packages (for included libraries).

But normally with that, I should be able to compile. I defined the build command line to `mingw32-make` but there are errors and I do not know if they are due to packets or something else.

So my question is : How to install packages and how to be sure that I use mingw64-gcc for compilation ?

Comment: Do you want to build the library for use on Windows or Linux?

Comment: @RustyX First I want to use it for windows, and if it works I will try to build it for android (don't know if it is possible)

Comment: Visual Studio won't make this process easier, only harder. I would just install mingw64-make, add the bin folder to the PATH and run `make` from the command line.

Comment: I need CMAKE to create a MinGW Makefiles. When I run cmake command with the -G "MinGW Makefiles" tag it does't work. When I run cmake without the -G it generates Visual Studio 2019 but I need to mingw32-make afterwards to get an exe. I just want an exe.